# Unable to get bool data type

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Newbie in C#.
Trying to use the below code to check if a certain bucket exists in S3.

```
using System;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Util;

namespace CRO
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "123");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "456");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION", "ap-southeast-2");

            Console.WriteLine(DoesBucketExist("randombucket").GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }


        public static async Task<bool> DoesBucketExist(string bucketName)
        {
            using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")))
            {
                DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine("Current date and time: " + currentDateTime);

                return await AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExistV2Async(s3Client, bucketName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a boolean value (true or false) to be returned.
But when I check the data type below is what I get instead of a "boolean".

> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Boolean,CRO.Program+d__1]

Very new to the C# world. Just wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Trying with .net core if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from the async method, you should use `await`. Also, you should change the `Main` method to an asynchronous method.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine(await DoesBucketExist("randombucket"));
}
```

[`Object.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-7.0) returns the type name of the instance.

Comment: Thanks it works. What is the need to have the "Task" keyword in the Main method?
Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: The `Task` is the return type of the async method, which is used when you don't want to return value when completed. For your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types